# Default value of Gateway in route o/p

Tags: networking, route, gateway

The output of the route command is coming as below. This is in a virtual machine.
My question is that why the value of Gateway for default destination coming as "gateway" and not as the IP Address of my router?? Also why are there two rows for eth0?

[image: Route command result]

Comment: can you add more info, like distro ?

Comment: @WissamAl-Roujoulah Its a Centos 7

Comment: There are not two rows *for* `eth0` any more than there are two rows *for* flags being `U`.  There is one row *for* each destination, and two of the destinations call for using interface `eth0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of Gateway for default destination coming as "gateway" because `route` command is resolving the name of the `IP`, so if you want to show the `IP` use `route -n` that tell it to not resolve the names. look to the man page of `route` for more info.

For the second question, one raw for the subnet of the network which is `10.0.2.0/24` and the other one is for the default gateway, so in this case the gateway is in the subnet `10.0.2.0/24`, and it's possible to have more than two raws that have `eth0` in the `Iface` field like when you have aliases on that interface so it's not a strange case